# Database - synchronized execution of update queries on different records

Tags: database, oracle, synchronization, sql-update

I have a table structure like this:

ParentObject(ObjectId string,.....)

ChildObject(ObjectId string, ParentId String, Atribute1 String, State Integer....)

There are multiple ParentObject records(nearly 1000) and each ParentObject record table is referenced by multiple records(nearly 50) in ChildObject table.

I have two parallel processes running on different machines which execute this query in a loop using OCI library calls.

`UPDATE ChildObject SET Attribute1='<process_name>' WHERE ObjectId = ANY 
   (SELECT TOP 100 ObjectId FROM ChildObject alias1 WHERE State = 0 
      AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM ChildObject alias2 WHERE alias2.State = 0 AND 
            alias2.Attribute1 <> ' ' AND alias2.ParentId = alias1.ParentId))`

The syntax might not be perfect. The logic is that each process updates 100 ChildObject records in a run and sets Attribute1 to the Process name(if not already set), sleeps for some time and starts the update again.

My Requirement is that all the ChildObject records referencing to the same ParentObject record should be updated by one process. For example, if Process1 updates 10 records of ChildObject that have the same ParentId, the remaining records of ChildObject that have the same ParentId should be updated by Process1 and not by Process2.

Since the processes are running parallely, some of the ChildObject records are updated in one process and some of the ChildObject records having the same ParentId are updated in the other process.

Select.. For Update doesn't work in my case because the update happens on different records in the ChildObject table.

Locking the entire ChildObject table might not be a good solution.

Can you please suggest me how to achieve this synchronization?

Thanks,

Vanathi

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a ProcessName column to the ParentObject table.  A process that wants to update children first have to set the ProcessName on the parent if the ProcessName is null (include the condition in the update query, don't check it before).  Even if both processes try to set the parent ProcessName simultaneously, only one will succeed.  The process then reads the ProcessName of the parent, and if it's its own name, continues to update the children.

If you can't add or modify tables, how about changing your query to:

```
UPDATE ChildObject
SET Attribute1='<process_name>'
WHERE ObjectId = ANY (
    SELECT TOP 100 ObjectId
    FROM ChildObject alias1
    WHERE State = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM ChildObject alias2
        WHERE alias2.Attribute1 <> ' '
          AND alias2.Attribute1 <> '<process_name>'
          AND alias2.ParentId = alias1.ParentId
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. That would be the best solution indeed. But I have a restriction that new columns cannot be added to the table. Can you please let me know if any other solution could be possible?

Comment: Can you create a new table?  If so, you can do the same if you make a table with ObjectId PK and ProcessName column.  Only difference is that you have to insert rows into the new table instead of updating them.

Comment: Any DDL modifications cannot be done at this stage. I would definitely use this approach in the next release of the application. But currently, I have to control this behaviour from code and DDL modifications are not permitted.

Comment: Do you change ChildObject.state when you process the records?

Comment: Yes. After this update query, each process executes a select query to fetch all the records with the process name updated and modifies the State.

Answer (score 0):

Just lock the parent row as the first step.  That will prevent any other session (that has the same locking mechanism) from processing that row

```
SELECT *
  FROM ParentObject
 WHERE ObjectID = <<whatever>>
   FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE ChildObject ...
```

Depending on the Oracle version and exactly what you're doing, you may not want threads to block waiting to lock the `ParentObject` row indefinitely.  You might want to do a `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`, catch the exception if you can't lock the parent row, and move on to the next row.  Or you may want to do a `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` to determine the next `ObjectID` to process.

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issue where multiple k8s pods are executing below update query parallely and getting into dead-lock

So, we need to lock the set of rows that the session 1 is going to update, which will prevent the other sessions from updating the same rows.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select group_slice_id,slice_id FROM queue_master
WHERE batch_run_id = 'STP_1693389464930_2015-04-03_1696424282917_1' AND COMPONENT_ID = '1_5'
AND Control_plane_pod_id is null AND status is null AND pod_id is null) WHERE rownum <= 10 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;


update queue_master set status = 'CP-IN-PROGRESS', 
START_TIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, control_plane_pod_id = 'cp-pod-1', CP_POD_IP='192.11.11.0'
where batch_run_id = 'STP_1693389464930_2015-04-03_1696424282917_1' and status is null and Control_plane_pod_id is null
and COMPONENT_ID = '1_5' and 
(group_slice_id,slice_id) in (select * from 
(select group_slice_id,slice_id from queue_master
where batch_run_id = 'STP_1693389464930_2015-04-03_1696424282917_1' and COMPONENT_ID = '1_5'
and Control_plane_pod_id is null and status is null and pod_id is null) where rownum <= 10 );
```

The select query with **FOR UPDATE** will lock those set of rows and lock will be released only after a commit or rollback

And the **FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED** will lock the next set of rows instead of waiting for the 1st session to release the lock